Dockerized OpenSearch not returning any hits for queries
I recently tried to move the chatbot project that I am working on over to OpenSearch. At first, my search function was working, but after dockerizing OpenSearch, I've run into the issue where my queries are not returning any hits. I tried to manually push a test vector into the vector store then search that same vector, but that too did not return a vector.
I'm not sure if the problem is with knn, with my OpenSearch configuration, or my searching/embedding code.
Here is the relevant code:
class OpenSearchVectorStore:
    def __init__(self, client, index_name):
        self.client = client
        self.index_name = index_name
        self.create_index_with_retries()

    def create_index_with_retries(self, retries=5, delay=10):
        for attempt in range(retries):
            try:
                self.create_index()
                return
            except Exception as e:
                logger.warning(f"Attempt {attempt + 1} to create index failed: {e}")
                if attempt < retries - 1:
                    time.sleep(delay)
        raise Exception("Failed to create index after several attempts")

    def create_index(self):
        if not self.client.indices.exists(index=self.index_name):
            self.client.indices.create(index=self.index_name, body={
                "mappings": {
                    "properties": {
                        "embedding": {"type": "knn_vector", "dimension": 768},
                        "metadata": {"type": "object"}
                    }
                }
            })

    def add_embedding(self, embedding, metadata):
        try:
            logger.info(f"Adding embedding for: {metadata}")
            self.client.index(index=self.index_name, body={
                "embedding": embedding,
                "metadata": metadata
            })
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error adding embedding to OpenSearch: {e}")

    def search(self, query_embedding, top_k=10):
        body = {
            "size": top_k,
            "query": {
                "knn": {
                    "embedding": {
                        "vector": query_embedding,
                        "k": top_k
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        logger.info(f"Sending search query to index '{self.index_name}': {body}")
        response = self.client.search(index=self.index_name, body=body)
        logger.info(f"Search response: {response}")
    
        if "hits" not in response or not response["hits"]["hits"]:
            logger.warning("No results found for the query.")
            return []
    
        return response["hits"]["hits"]

    def as_retriever(self):
        return self

    def get_relevant_documents(self, query):
        embeddings = TogetherEmbeddings(
            model="togethercomputer/m2-bert-80M-2k-retrieval",
            together_api_key="368345e796a144690ec70eb930cdc861007efdbeb5caf744f0d14783970af43a",
        )
        query_embedding = embeddings.embed_query(query)
        logger.info(f"Query embedding: {query_embedding}")
        results = self.search(query_embedding)
        if not results:
            logger.warning("No relevant documents found.")
            return []
        documents = []
        for result in results:
            documents.append({
                "page_content": result["_source"]["metadata"]["page_content"],
                "metadata": result["_source"]["metadata"]
            })
        return documents

My manual opensearch command results:
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/pdf_documents/_doc" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "embedding": [
    -0.20050155,
    0.24337491,

# generated:

...
   0.09113836,
    0.2135575
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "file_url": "test_document_url",
    "page_number": 1
  }
}'

# The query with the same vector generated:

curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/pdf_documents/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "knn": {
      "embedding": {
        "vector": [
          -0.20050155,
          0.24337491,
...

# generated:

{
  "took" : 344,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}

I'm really at a loss here...

If the code works, why do you include that? If the Docker integration is the problem, why don't you include details about that?

A lot of the code changed post-dockerization. I'm no longer sure whether the issue is stemming from the dockerization or the code itself. I'm new to coding and messed up--didn't save a version where opensearch was functional. At this point I think that I should just restart pre-opensearch and reintegrate everything all over again.
